# Find sequence number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

This is my table in SQL Server :

```
number     grade    weight
--------------------------
  1         1         185
  2         1         179
  3         3         191
  4         3         192
  5         3         193
  6         1         194
  7         1         196
  8         1         188
  9         1         187
  10        1         200
  11        2         201
  12        2         202
  13        2         203
  14        2         191
  15        2         187
```

and I want this output in SQL Server without any temp table :

```
Number     grade     weight
----------------------------
 1-2         1        364
 3-5         3        576
 6-10        1        965
 11-15       2        984
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: sql-server, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. I think the simplest approach is to take the difference between `number` and a computed `row_number()`:

```
select 
    concat(min(number), '-', max(number)) number,
    grade,
    sum(weight) weight
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by grade order by number) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by grade, number - rn
order by min(number)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83a96082061bc3e8757fccb887534ae2)**:

```
number | grade | weight
:----- | ----: | -----:
1-2    |     1 |    364
3-5    |     3 |    576
6-10   |     1 |    965
11-15  |     2 |    984
```

Comment: Thank you very much .